# Python. Issue with my interactive story

Tags: python

I here have pasted in some code from my interactive story where I want to let the user choose a car for a character and make it be used throughout the story but as I am new with python I may have done this completely wrong.

```
print("Help Rick P. choose a car to drive.")

print()

print("1 Chevrolet Camaro")
print("2 Chevrolet SS Sedan")
print("3 BMW M3 Sedan")
print("4 Mercedes-Benz GLE Coupé")

print()

def cars(car):
    Camaro = car1
    SS_Sedan = car2
    M3_Sedan = car3
    GLE_Coupé = car4

def choice_car():
    car = input("Input the corresponding number to the car that you'd like Rick P. to drive... ")
    print()
    cars(car)

choice_car()

print(car)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need help to make it possible to let a user choose a car for the character

Comment: You might want to reread a python tutorial. You've got quite a few issues here that are covered early in most tutorials.

Comment: I will do so. Thanks for taking your time to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

cars = OrderedDict([(1, 'Camaro'), (2, 'SS Sedan'), (3, 'M3 Sedan'), (4, 'GLE Coupé')])

print('Help Rick P. choose a car to drive.\n')
print('\n'.join([str(key) + ' ' + val for key, val in cars.items()]) + '\n')

def choice_car(invalid = False):
    if invalid:
        choice = int(input('Invalid car. Try again...\n'))
    else:
        choice = int(input('Input the corresponding number to the car that you\'d like Rick P. to drive...\n'))
    car = cars.get(choice)
    if not car:
        return choice_car(True)
    return car

car = choice_car()

print(car)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have taken the liberty to interpret your question in an open way. It seems that you want to do something, but you are unsure of how to do it. I will provide an answer to help you learn both how to debug the program, and how to thing algorithmically.

The first part of the program is nearly correct. There's nothing too wrong about it. What you want to do is to select a car from the printed selection. The issue with the code is this part:

```
def cars(car):
    Camaro = car1
    SS_Sedan = car2
    M3_Sedan = car3
    GLE_Coupé = car4
```

This is wrong in many ways. First of all, `car1`, `car2` et al, will not work as you assume they will. Python will try to find objects named `car1`, `car2` et al, in the function's local scope. [ref](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/executionmodel.html) If it doesn't find it, it will search for a binding of that variable in the global space. If it isn't found it will raise a `NameError`.

Besides, this code will not allow you to select the car. What you want to do is: **check what value the parameter `car` contains**, and based on that return a specific value. You would do something with an `if/elif` statement like that:

```
def cars(car):
    if car == 1:
        return 'Camaro'
    elif car == 2:
        return 'SS_Sedan'
    elif car == 3:
        return 'M3_Sedan'
    elif car == 4:
        return 'GLE_Coupe'
```

Now, good practice also has it that you account for input that is not what is expected. In this case, having an extra `else` case account for the erroneous input, and letting the user now about that might be a good idea, so you could add that too.

```
... (snip) ...
elif car == 4:
    return 'GLE_Coupe'
else:
    return 'Invalid Car'  # you could return None or even better raise an exception, but since you are a beginner let's keep it simple
```

Notice, that in all cases your function is returning a `string` that contains the car model, and is not just binding random objects to names. What you have coded, if it worked as you expected it, would be something akin to an enumeration (you might want to read about [enums here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to not use a cars function, but a cars [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). If you want a function to return a value, then use a [return](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html) statement.

On a side note, your code makes it look as if you haven't really studied a [Python tutorial](http://www.diveintopython3.net/). Please do.

```
cars = ['Camaro',
        'SS Sedan', 
        'M3 Sedan',
        'GLE Coupé']

def choose_car():
    car = int(input("Input the corresponding number to the car that you'd like Rick P. to drive... \n")) + 1
    return cars[car]
```

Or if you don't want to work with turning a string into an [integer](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/integer.html), use a [dictionary](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html).

```
cars = {'1': 'Camaro',
        '2': 'SS Sedan', 
        '3': 'M3 Sedan',
        '4': 'GLE Coupé'}

def choose_car():
    car = input("Input the corresponding number to the car that you'd like Rick P. to drive... \n")
    return cars[car]
```